# How to properly echo a php variable in a string for url href?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, concatenation, echo

I'm trying to change the url of a link on my wordpress site thru a PHP function. So far echoing out the string url is giving me trouble.

I have the following in my PHP file.

```
$siteurl = site_url(); // gives me: "http://localhost/testsite"

 $teststring = "/catalog";

$entireurl = $siteurl.$teststring; //gives me "http://localhost/testsite/catalog"

function change_site($buffer) {
$in = array('<a href="http://localhost/testsite/type/combined/?case=main" title="Catalog">');
$out = array('<a href="'.$entireurl.'" title="Catalog">');
  return (str_replace($in, $out, $buffer));
}
ob_start("change_site");
```

Currently, the link takes on the link of another href link in the same div. (bizzare)

Comment: just try `$entireurl = $siteurl.$teststring;` insted of  `$entireurl = $siteurl." ".$teststring;`

Comment: dont use echo just use this simply array('<a href="'.$entireurl.'" title="Catalog">');

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. You might be missing the . concatenator

```
$out = array('<a href="'.$entireurl.'" title="Catalog">');
```

Comment: Great! I don't get the error anymore, but now the link does not set. If I use $out = array('<a href="http://localhost/testsite/catalog" title="Catalog">'); it works. do you think because the URL var is a string?

Comment: try
`$entireurl = $siteurl.$teststring;`

Comment: So bizzare now, the link is the link to another a href link that I have on my site (within the same div)